# What to do if a user profile contains some kind of rudeness?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, behavior

I came across a [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830196/ryan-wilson) which has some rudeness in his title.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Rude Title in Profile Section]

Is this kind of title allowed here on Stack Overflow? (or on all Stack Exchange sites?). Isn't that against the [be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)?

What's the best way to deal with this? Ignore it or should I flag one of his posts for a moderator attention and explain the situation?

Comment: (Safe to assume that he's no longer a full stack developer at *wherever* they previously were...)

Comment: Uber-meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208551/175248

Comment: The profile info has been tidied up.

Comment: I used to work at that place. Very uncomfortable working conditions.

Comment: Too bad, now even he doesn't work there anymore.